Why netboot makes all filesystems as readonly!
I have installed ubuntu 22.04 on hdd1 and installed another ubuntu 22.04 on hdd2. Both can boot with no problem. I've installed dhcp, nfs, ntp, pxe, ssh servers on hdd1 and configured them to make hdd1 the server. Also, mounted hdd2 in /media/nfshdd and exported it in nfs exports. Changed the hdd2 fstab and replaced the local disk by <server ip>:/media/nfshdd as an nfs filesystem. Connected another PC and configured its BIOS to boot from pxe-lan. The system obtains ip from dhcp, loads vmlinuz and initramfs from tftp and mounts media/nfshdd as / but systemd cannot load many units and there is no GUI, no ssh, no logs, ... and no user can login even from tty1.
What is the problem of systemd with netboot?
(P.S.: I had made initramfs as BOOT=nfs and MODULES=netboot and put it in tftp server)
UPDATE:
I tried to execute a simple script in boot process using rc.local and its link in init.d. The script checks the ip address, cuts the last number in ip and makes a hostname as node$(lastpart of ip). The script works fine as the hostname changes correctly.
I used this script to check whether I have access to different directories. So, I put some cp commands to copy a file into /var/log, /var, /etc, /usr, /etc and /home/user. But when the script runs, none of the cp commands executed. I don't know why but all of the directories seem to be read only despite the mount command shows they are mounted with rw option or something prevents `cp command from writing into directories.
UPDATE2:
Finally, I captured a flying message in boot process just in a glance by capturing video from monitor by camera!!!! It tells that the filesystems are read only! Although the mount command output shows rw option in / mount point. What caused the filesystem to be read only? Here is my /etc/exports file in server:
/media/nfshdd     192.168.2.0/24 (rw,no_root_squash,async,insecure,no_subtree_check

and this is the /etc/fstab in client:
192.168.2.50:/media/nfshdd    /   nfs  auto,rw,nouser,exec,nolock,async,nofail,noatime,_netdev,ac,bg 0 0
tempfs  /tmp      tmpfs   defaults   0 0 
sysfs   /sys      sysfs   defaults   0 0
proc    /proc     proc    defaults   0 0


Do you have a writable /var and /tmp?

@vidarlo: I already put tmp and var in fstab with rw option but then I found out that the system mounts them even if they are not pointed out in fstab. should I do anything more than this?

You should probably include more of your configuration. Is /tmp and /var shared between systems? What does your /etc/exports look like? Have you specified no_root_squash?

I have only shared /media/nfshdd directory in server's /etc/exports  and inserted it in client /etc/fstsab as 192.168.2.50:/media/nfshdd     /    nfs    defaults,nolock 0 0. Also, I've inserted tmpfs   /tmp   tmpfs   defaults   0 0 and similar for /var and /proc ,... but then I read that the new kernels mount these system directories by default and there is no need to insert them in fstab. I've also changed mount options in fstab but nothing changed

@vidarlo: I have specified no_root_squash and no_subtree_check in exports

finally, I found the problem. there was an extra space!!!! in /etc/exports before (rw I had inserted a space that silently denied the parenthesis! thanks to https://serverfault.com/a/1033554
